# list of dictionaries into new columns

Tags: python, dictionary

I have that df where one of the columns contains string-encoded list of Python dictionaries. Example of only one row in a column:

```py
"""[
   {
      "cast_id":14,
      "character":"Woody (voice)",
      ,
      "gender":2,
      "id":31,
      "name":"Tom Hanks"
   },
   {
      "cast_id":15,
      "character":"Buzz Lightyear (voice)",
      "gender":2,
      "id":12898,
      "name":"Tim Allen"
   },
   {
      "cast_id":16,
      "character":"Mr. Potato Head (voice)",
      "gender":2,
      "id":7167,
      "name":"Don Rickles"
   },
   {
      "cast_id":17,
      "character":"Slinky Dog (voice)",
      "gender":2,
      "id":12899,
      "name":"Jim Varney"
   },
   {
      "cast_id":18,
      "character":"Rex (voice)",
      "gender":2,
      "id":12900,
      "name":"Wallace Shawn"
   },
   {
      "cast_id":19,
      "character":"Hamm (voice)",
      "gender":2,
      "id":7907,
      "name":"John Ratzenberger"
   }
]"""
```

the type of that cell is string

What I must do, is to convert this One column into few new columns with heathers: cast_id, character, name, gender, etc.
I have no idea where to start from, any suggestion or tip most welcome

update:
original DF columns: Index(['cast', 'crew', 'id'], dtype='object')

created df with only one column and assign to new variable:
cast_only = credits['cast']

type(cast_only[0])   -   str

Comment: A column in what? you should still show your attempts and research into solving this yourself.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by where the data is going, maybe edit it with a picture?

Comment: I assume what he is trying to say is he has a column filled with dictionaries. The dictionaries themselves are consisted of key value pairs, from which he wants to create a data frame for keys as columns as the corresponding values as data. For each dictionary a row.

Comment: @edusanketdk thank You, yes that what I am trying to achieve, the only solutions I know of would work on single list that I can assign to variable and than I would probably use Json, but I don't know how to approach this whole column, that contains 45k rows with these list of dictionaries...

Comment: can you please type what you want to get as an output

Comment: the name of the columns: cast_id, character, name, gender

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it well, what you need as a first step is to convert the string into a Python dictionary. You can use the [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) method for this:

```
import ast

string = "[{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)'...}]"

# We convert the string to a Python dictionary
obj = ast.literal_eval(string)
```

However, this will fail if the dictionary is not well-formed in the string, and it your case it looks like so:

`: 'Woody (voice)', , 'gender': 2,`  (note the two sibling commas)

Comment: Good catch on that extra comma.

Comment: the double commas its just my mistake,  I was modifying a little this list as its much longer than I posted. That list/string I posted it is just a single row, I have column with 45k lines like this. I can't pass list into variable as in your solution. Any other way to do that?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand exactly why you can't use the code. Could you please show how you get that column string?

Comment: @Sylwi you really need to provide us with the dataframe (at least two lines). The above is the right way to do it.

Comment: I am sorry for not being precise enough but I don't know how to better present this. I have a dataframe, where one of the column contains rows with the above string - list of dictionaries. There is 45k of rows with similar string. I am new to Python and what I don't know is how can I make from that one column many columns. I have the following columns: Index(['cast', 'crew', 'id'], dtype='object'). How can I convert that column cast into several columns, like; cast_id, name, gender, etc.

Comment: @ Sherlock Bourne, I have created variable the whole column = cast_only, I have passed this to your solution as follows: obj = ast.literal_eval(cast_only) and got the following error: Name: cast, Length: 45476, dtype: object, malformed node or string: 0

Comment: @Sylwi Could you please update the question with the code you used to store the text in the variable `cast_only`? The error is saying that the variable does not contain a string if I am not wrong

Comment: OK so, now that you are able to have the strings containing the lists of dictionaries, you should be able to call the `ast.literal_eval` method for each string, and with the resulting dictionaries, get their keys (because if I am not wrong that's what you want). Is there anything wrong about that?